# Change legend symbol from geom_boxplot symbol to a square

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, boxplot

Can I change the symbol used in the legend for a boxplot? I would like to use a square instead of the boxplot symbol that is the default. I've tried the following after some searching, however the last line does not seem to have an effect:

```
df = data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = sample(letters[1:2], 10, TRUE))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(y, x)) +
geom_boxplot(aes(color = y)) +
guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 22)))
```

The reason is that there is another graph left of this one that uses the same colors but points instead of a boxplot, so I would like a legend that works for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess there are multiple ways to achieve what you want, but what I usually do is:

1. Remove boxplot legend
2. Add `geom_point` layer with size `0`
3. Change legend for `geom_point` and NOT for `geom_boxplot`

Code:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), 
                 y = sample(letters[1:2], 10, TRUE))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(y, x, color = y)) +
    # Add dummy point layer with invisible points (size 0)
    geom_point(size = 0, shape = 22) +
    # Don't show legend
    geom_boxplot(show.legend = FALSE) +
    # Increase point size
    guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 10)))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That works fine, thanks. However it gives me just the box outline, a filled box would be much nicer. However when change "color = y" to fill, I just get tiny points in the legend. Hmm...

Comment: Figured it out, "color = y" goes in the top, "fill = y" in the geom_point() statement.

Answer (score 3):

Not pretty, but you could hack it like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = sample(letters[1:2], 10, TRUE))

df_sum <- df %>% group_by(y) %>% summarize(mean_x = mean(x))

ggplot(df, aes(y, x)) +
  geom_point(data = df_sum, aes(y, mean_x, color = y), shape = 22) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(color = y), show.legend = F)
```

[image]